# How to include interaction term in global macro for use in the reghdfe command?

Tags: regression, stata, interaction, stata-macros

I want to create an interaction term in the *community-contributed* `regdhdfe` command.

One of the two interaction variables is a continuous variable and used with a global. The other variable is a gender dummy.

My code looks something like this:

```
clear all
set obs 25000

local vlist v0 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 z4 z5 z6 

foreach v of local vlist { 
    generate `v' = runiform()
}


rename v8 i_female 
replace i_female=0 if i_female<0.5
replace i_female=1 if i_female>=0.5

foreach num of numlist 4 5 6 {
    global varlist_`num' "v`num' z`num'"
}

foreach num of numlist 4 5 6 {
    reghdfe v0 ${varlist_`num'} ${varlist_`num'}#i.i_female if v1<0.8, absorb(v7)
}
```

This returns the following error:

> error: there are repeated variables: 
>       r(198);

Comment: You do not refer to the global correctly. Which variables do you want after v0 and which in the `absorb` option?

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly already published the question, when it still needed editing. Will try to make it more clear in a minute.

Comment: Your new example does not give the error you mention. Also note that `v7` is not a factor variable in your example.

Comment: Assuming the variables are correct in your actual data, you need to use `i.i_female` for the gender dummy and `i.v7` in the `vce` option. The question of where the interaction term should go is a substantive one and no one can tell you that without knowing what you are trying to do. Chances are it should go in the 'normal regression' part. Are you sure you need to use the `absorb` option?

Comment: I have incorporated the prefix i. for the variable i_female now and stated the error which I get (which is a different one than the one given before). The absorb option is required by reghdfe, but in my actual data is not a problem, because I always use gender-age fixed effects in the absorb part.

Comment: The current problem is fairly self-explanatory. I think you should think more carefully before you post (particularity in the comments where you keep deleting previous ones).

Comment: Duely noted. Sorry for that - still not so familiar with stackoverflow. Will try to be more careful. Why is the problem self-explanatory? What I would want is that the regression includes all of the variables included in the macro, both as a stand-alone variable and additionally also interacted with the gender dummy. So that, if we leave aside the macro for a second, it would look like: ` reghdfe v0 v4 z4 v4*i_female z4*i_female, absorb (v7)

Comment: Do you have a suggestion, how I would do that, using the macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want and what you instruct Stata to do in the above code are two
different things.

Stata complains that there are repeated variables because when the macros expand you do not get `v4 z4 v4*i_female z4*i_female`.

Instead the variables `v4`, `v5` and `v6` are duplicated:

```
foreach num of numlist 4 5 6 {
    global varlist_`num' "v`num' z`num'"
}

foreach num of numlist 4 5 6 {
    display "v0 ${varlist_`num'} ${varlist_`num'}#i.i_female if v1<0.8, absorb(v7)"
}

v0 v4 z4 v4 z4#i.i_female if v1<0.8, absorb(v7)
v0 v5 z5 v5 z5#i.i_female if v1<0.8, absorb(v7)
v0 v6 z6 v6 z6#i.i_female if v1<0.8, absorb(v7)
```

In order to get the desired output, you need to modify your code as follows:

```
foreach num of numlist 4 5 6 {
    global varlist1_`num' "v`num' z`num'"
    global varlist2_`num' "v`num'#i.i_female z`num'#i.i_female"
}

foreach num of numlist 4 5 6 {
    display "v0 ${varlist1_`num'} ${varlist2_`num'} if v1<0.8, absorb(v7)"
}

v0 v4 z4 v4#i.i_female z4#i.i_female if v1<0.8, absorb(v7)
v0 v5 z5 v5#i.i_female z5#i.i_female if v1<0.8, absorb(v7)
v0 v6 z6 v6#i.i_female z6#i.i_female if v1<0.8, absorb(v7)
```

Comment: I see no reason to write `foreach num of numlist 4 5 6` when you can write `forval num=4/6`. Naturally this is a trivial detail in context and you're just copying the OP. But there is no virtue in writing complicated code.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. There is no need for global macros either.